# How to debug intermittent slow VMware startup and shutdown times

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I've been running 64-bit versions of Windows 7 and Ubuntu or Centos Linux under VMware for a while. Usually things work very well, but sometimes the VM startup or shutdown times can be pretty long. Sometimes it's couple of minutes, sometimes it can be longer, closer to 5 minutes. Eventually, the system does start or shutdown, so there is no hang, just a delay.  And when the VM is actually running, it works fine.

My question is how can I debug the cause of the long startup/shutdown times? Are there any VMware gurus out there that have looked into this before?

I'm currently running VMware version 10.0.2 build-1744117 under Windows 7 64-bit.